# Server 2008 32 bit SP2 random BSOD

Tags: windows, bsod

First time poster, so please excuse if I forget anything here. I have a Windows Server 2008 SP2 32 bit server running on VMware ESXi 5.1 that is randomly dumping and rebooting itself. I have been digging around, and it seems to be related to a network driver issue, but I'm not positive on that. This is our production intranet web server running IBM's WebSphere. I began to install Windows updates to his machine in a hope that it would address the issue, but just made it worse.  It BSOD'd twice in 12 hours so I have rolled the server back.  I'm having issues getting any more info from these minidumps, can anyone help me out?

```
==================================================
Dump File         : Mini031414-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 3/14/2014 2:47:59 PM
Bug Check String  : MULTIPLE_IRP_COMPLETE_REQUESTS
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000044
Parameter 1       : 0xa129a150
Parameter 2       : 0x00000e7a
Parameter 3       : 0x00000000
Parameter 4       : 0x00000000
Caused By Driver  : tdx.sys
Caused By Address : tdx.sys+edbc
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+cdb3f
Stack Address 1   : ntkrnlpa.exe+a75bb
Stack Address 2   : tdx.sys+5654
Stack Address 3   : tcpip.sys+5c633
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Users\jwilliam\Desktop\Portal\Mini031414-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 1
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 6002
Dump File Size    : 165,464
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : Mini071613-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 7/16/2013 1:55:46 PM
Bug Check String  : MULTIPLE_IRP_COMPLETE_REQUESTS
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000044
Parameter 1       : 0xa1df8008
Parameter 2       : 0x00000e7a
Parameter 3       : 0x00000000
Parameter 4       : 0x00000000
Caused By Driver  : tdx.sys
Caused By Address : tdx.sys+edbc
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+cdb3f
Stack Address 1   : ntkrnlpa.exe+a75bb
Stack Address 2   : tdx.sys+5654
Stack Address 3   : tcpip.sys+5c633
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Users\jwilliam\Desktop\Portal\Mini071613-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 1
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 6002
Dump File Size    : 168,856
==================================================
```

Comment: You are right in suspecting a network interface driver. Try using a different type of NIC - if vmxnet3 try e1000, or vice versa.

Comment: Do you have an antivirus running on the machine? There's a chance its "network scanner" is causing havoc with your network drivers.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to update your drivers, and more than one driver at that.

[Check out the MSDN page for that error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558982%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

---

### Cause

A driver has called IoCompleteRequest to ask that an IRP be completed, but the packet has already been completed.

### Resolution

This is a tough bug to find because the simplest case -- a driver that attempted to complete its own packet twice -- is usually not the source of the problem. More likely, two separate drivers each believe that they own the packet, and each has attempted to complete it. The first request succeeds, and the second fails, resulting in this bug check.

Tracking down which drivers in the system caused the error is difficult, because the trail of the first driver has been covered by the second. However, the driver stack for the current request can be found by examining the device object fields in each of the stack locations.

---

Comment: Yeah, I had read that page but still don't really know where to go.  My network drivers are up to date, and Windows Updates are available, but gave me a different, much more frequent BSOD.

Comment: @Jason try a different vNIC type, investigate your WebSphere version (and its available updates), and for that matter, look into the issue being related to firmware levels on the physical hardware, or even an ESXi issue.  Fun, fun.

Comment: I thought about the vNIC actually.  I know WebSphere is out of date, I'll get with the programmer to see what the possibilities are there.  Sadly, since this is prod, I don't many opportunities to take it down.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JasonW Also, if you haven't done so already, hit up Google about tdx.sys and BSODs.  See if you can figure out what's using that driver on your server - seems to be used by a lot of A/V products, and showing up in BSODs for a lot of Windows versions...